# Multithread proxy change but once

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, tor

Let say I have a code like this:

```
def func1(a,b,c):
    try:
        p = pycurl.Curl()

        p.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, "127.0.0.1")
        p.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 9050)
        p.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)

        p.perform()
        p.close()

    except pycurl.error as error:
        if error[0] == 28:   # timeout - change proxy
            print "Tor timeout, need to change"
            queue.put((a,b,c))
            new_tor()
            return

def new_tor():
    # send_signal_for_new_ident_is_here
```

I start this code in 7 threads.
And when a thread receives error 28 it change the identify.
But it happens that ALL 7 THREADS sending signal to change identify.

How to do this:
If thread received error 28, then it calls new_tor() and other 6 threads don't but waiting for result and only then they proceed to work. How to sync this?

Answer (score 0):

Just put an error "id" into the queue and if you encounter it, put the value back into the queue, and then handle as needed.

You don't wish to end the thread, which is what I did.
So, you can have some unique identifier for each thread, such that if once a thread encounters an error, it also adds the data (it's identifier) that says it encountered this error before, so that if all threads have encountered this error, the error is removed from the queue.

Code:

```
import threading
import Queue
y = 0
def f1():
    global y
    y += 1
    if y > 100:
        raise ValueError('trial')
def f2():
    return

class Test(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func = func
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        while True:
            x = ''
            if not queue.empty():
                x = queue.get()
                if x == 'error':
                    queue.put(x)
                    print 'Stopping %s' % (self.name,)
                    return
            try:
                self.func()
            except Exception as e:
                queue.put('error')

queue = Queue.Queue()
thread1 = Test(f1, '1')
thread2 = Test(f2, '2')

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```